# Excel - summing two IF statements where fail criteria is text, how to prevent #VALUE?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a excel formula that sums two IF statements (checking data in a active tab, and archive tab).

the **value_if_false** writes the text "TBD".

The issue is if both IF statements are false, then excel tries to do "TBD"+"TBD" and it can't add summ text so it does #VALUE

Any ideas on solution? 
I thought if the 2nd IF statement (archive data) the fail criteria could be to just do nothing but not sure how to make it a formula.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the whole in an IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(...,"TBD")
```

where `...` is your formula.  Then when it errors it will return `TBD` instead.

Comment: That does work! Thank you. Only issue I see is if there is a different kind of error not related to "TBD"+"TBD" this added function could mask it